# SquirrelSQL won't start/open

Tags: squirrel-sql

I haven't been using my Squirrel SQL application in a while and when I tried to open it now, it loads all the plugins and then goes to the task bar but when you click on it, the window doesn't show. There's no error warning or anything it just goes to taskbar.

I tried reinsalling it with different versions and same happens, also clean the register and nothing

Right now i'm using DBeaver it's works alright also. but I'm curious of what happens with squirrel

Comment: Sounds like a Question for SuperUser and not Stackoverflow...

Comment: I look there but there was no tag for Squirrel SQL, so I came here and found it :D